# Dynamic Virtual Channels in RDP (Only built in domain admin account works)

Tags: rdp, virtual-channel

We have a virtual channel set up using the TsTeleport API.

Following are the parameters of our scenario better -

- We are passing a user identity from a client to an RDP session
- We have an application on the RDP server that loads the dll, then calls across to the client end to get the information
- It works fine only when the client machine is logged in as the built-in domain administrator on the machine we are RDP'ing to
- It does not seem to matter what account is used to initiate the Remote Desktop session, but as stated the virtual channel fails to open and is null
- There seems to be something going on with the logging-in into the local machine
- The client side pipe end dll was registered by that built in domain admin

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so as usual, after finally reaching out for help, I've found the solution. Regsvr32 only registered the dll under: `"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default\AddIns\"`

The CLSID needs to be registered for EVERY user before it will work for them. I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: If you use the syntax: `C:\path\to\myplugin.dll:{CLSID of library including IWTSPlugin coclass}` in that rigitry key. It should work without registering and even without Admin rights.